# download email in pdf format

Tags: java

I want to save all my emails into a PDF format. The file must contain all the information in mail and print it in pdf format.
Is there a java programming way to to this (cause hundreds of emails) ?

Comment: more info needed. what kind of email server do you use? do you use IMAP or POP? details please.

Answer (score 0):

**download email in pdf format**

here answer divided into two ways

1) read all the mail's of ("inbox") and store into collection.

2) and one by one write in to pdf file

get the all the mail's from email please refer link is
[Reading the full email from GMail using JavaMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928608/reading-the-full-email-from-gmail-using-javamail)

and writing  into pdf file so please refer link is [enter link description here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPDF/article.html)

in pdf use **itextpdf.jar file**

and give option as download

Comment: thanks for quick response ... i could write it in pdf format but how do i download and save in my local machine first

Comment: use following links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928608/reading-the-full-email-from-gmail-using-javamail

Comment: use another link like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825887/how-to-write-java-program-to-read-new-emails-from-any-emailid